# awk to output the percentage of a field compared to length

Tags: awk

The `awk` below using the sample input would output the following: Basically, it averages the text in `$5` that matches if `7 < 30`.

```
awk '{if(len==0){last=$5;total=$7;len=1;getline}if($5!=last){printf("%s\t%f\n", last, total/len);last=$5;total=$7;len=1}else{total+=$7;len+=1}}END{printf("%s\t%f\n", last, total/len)}' Input.txt > output.txt
```

**Sample Input**

```
chr 1   955542  955763  +   AGRN:exon.1 1   0
chr 1   955542  955763  +   AGRN:exon.1 2   0
chr 1   955542  955763  +   AGRN:exon.1 3   0
chr 1   955542  955763  +   AGRN:exon.1 4   1
chr 1   955542  955763  +   AGRN:exon.1 5   1
chr 1   955542  955763  +   AGRN:exon.1 6   1
....
....
chr 1   955542  955763  +   AGRN:exon.1 218 32
chr 1   955542  955763  +   AGRN:exon.1 219 32
chr 1   955542  955763  +   AGRN:exon.1 220 32
chr 1   955542  955763  +   AGRN:exon.1 221 29
```

**Output**

```
AGRN:exon.1 4.5714285
```

My question is I can not seem to add the correct syntax that will also output the total # of lines in `$6` that represent `$5` and the % of `7 < 30`  I know my words may not be all that helpful so hopefully the desired output will help.  Thank you :).

**Desired output**

```
AGRN:exon.1 4.5714285 3.16742% (221 (# of lines in `6' / 7 #3 of lines `< 30`)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think your program does what you say.  Regardless this might be what you're looking for

```
$ awk '$8<30{a[$6]+=$7;c[$6]++} 
            {t[$6]++} 
         END{for(i in a) print i,a[i]/c[i],(100*c[i]/t[i])"% ("t[i]" lines)"}' file
```

will give (after removing the `...` rows from input file

```
AGRN:exon.1 34.5714 70% (10 lines)
```